# Stutter on presenting UIViewController with SpriteKit

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, uikit

My SpriteKit game has 2 UIViewControllers (i.e. navigations)

1. Default one - has SKView and presents game SKScenes, animated backgrounds...
2. Top one - presented on top of default, used for UI and HUD

Top one is presented like this

```
func presentViewControler(_ xib: AppXIB) {
  guard let dvc = makeViewController(for: xib.name) else {
    Log.e("Coudn't create VC for name: \(xib.name)")
    return
  }
  
  dvc.delegate = self
  dvc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
  
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.present(dvc, animated: false)
  }
}
```

When presenting it, small stutter occurs, and I'm suspecting it's because top UIViewController is presented on main thread ( wouldn't work without it), while default one uses update() which is also on main.

Questions are:

1. Am I presenting it the wrong way? Why it stutters?
2. Is there a better way to have system like this, meaning, having something like UINavigationController on top of another UINavigationController?

Any ideas are welcomed, including links to resources for this kind of architecture.

**EDIT** 
What i've tried to:

1. In main storyboard, create subview and use it as SKView, instead of using main view from UIViewController.
2. Create SKView programmatically and add it as child.
3. Present custom view on top, instead presenting modal UIViewController with its view
4. Use only one SKNode for animation and remove others.
5. Use SKAction for movement, instead update() function.

Everything was tested on 5,6 year old iPad, so maybe that has something to do with it? Testing on simulator works fine.